# Temporary file utility class in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, io

I decided to write a tiny class to automatically write and delete a file given filename and content. It is intended to make testing IO less verbose. I include a small example usage.

**`temporary.py`**

```
import os

class Temporary:
    def __init__(self, name, content):
        self.name = name
        self.content = content

    def __enter__(self):
        with open(self.name, 'w+') as f:
            f.write(self.content)

    def __exit__(self,_,__,___):
        os.remove(self.name)
```

**`first_word.py`**

```
import doctest
from temporary import Temporary

def first_word_of_each_line(filename):
    """
    >>> txt = '\\n'.join(['first line', 'second line', 'bar bar'])
    >>> with Temporary('foo.txt', txt): first_word_of_each_line('foo.txt')
    ['first', 'second', 'bar']
    """
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        return [line.split()[0] for line in lines]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Better to patch `open` using something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock

Comment: What was wrong with the various temporary file classes in the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module?

Comment: @GarethRees nothing this is just an exercise with `with` not intended to be used for serious purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There, well, really isn't much to review here, so I have just a couple of points on this.

- Add a docstring to the class `Temporary`. Describe what this class does in detail, and flesh it out with useful information about arguments as well.
- You're missing some whitespace in between parameters in your `__exit__` declaration. It should look like this `def __exit__(self, _, __, ___)`.
- You should add a method like `write_to_file` so that the user can change the contents of the file during runtime, before it's deleted.
- As mentioned by [@GarethRees](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11728/gareth-rees), there's already a Python module built for this kind of use, [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

I hope this helps! If there's anything else that you want me to cover on this, mention it in the comments, and I'll see if I can cover it.